# Use of IDP Certificate

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-saml

We are implementing a SSO as a service provider and multiple clients can configure their metadata xml and certificate with our application.I have successfully integrated our application with spring SAML extension.But i want to know what is the use of IDP provided certificate because the application works fine without certificate also.

Answer (score 2):

Everybody can create a SAML Response for your SP if he knows your urls and issuer. By checking the signature with the IdPs certificate you can prove that the message comes from the right origin and not from the bad guys.

I think spring-saml does not work without a IDP-certificate in either your keystore or your idp-metadata-xml.
But what you can skip is signing the metadata (to check if this is not manipulated) or SSL/TLS encryption (to secure the transportation) with certificates.